# When should I use dilated convolution?

Tags: convolution

I read the [wavenet](https://blog.acolyer.org/2017/03/24/a-miscellany-of-fun-deep-learning-papers/) paper and I am clear about why they used Dilated Convolution. According to it they used this for give the causal property for the model. Where they wanted to introduced a sequential behavior . But lot of posts say it can use to increase the receptive field. Can some give me simple examples where we can use this in signal processing domain CNN + LSTM) and vision domain.